# Entity Framework Get Top 5 Record For All Categories

Tags: entity-framework

I have a query for get top 5 records for all categories:

```
Select * From 
  (Select News.Title,
          News.Url,
          Images.Url ImageUrl,
          (Select CategoryName From Categories Where Id = News.CategoryId) CategoryName,
          Rank() Over (Partition By CategoryID Order By News.Date Desc) as Rank From News
          Cross Apply (Select Top 1 Images.Url From Images Where News.Id = Images.NewsId) Images)
News Where Rank <= 5
```

I want to write same query in entity framework. Because this query works very slow. What can I write this?

Comment: Actually EF will be slower here. It generates a lot more query code. Try optimizing this query by adding indexes to the tables you are selecting from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you've got your database and Entity Framework context properly configured with foreign key relationships and navigation properties, the following query should give you what you're expecting:

```
Categories
    .SelectMany(c => c.News.OrderByDescending(n => n.Date).Take(5))
    .Select(n => new
    {
        n.Title,
        n.Url,
        ImageUrl = n.Images.Select(i => i.Url).FirstOrDefault(),
        CategoryName = n.Category.Name,
        n.Date
    });
```

It returns the Dates instead of the Ranks, but that can be done later on in code if absolutely necessary.

All this said, Entity Framework is not a magic bullet.  If your database is not properly indexed, slow queries will stay slow.